# create react app - without typescript , got Error: Failed to load parser '@typescript-eslint/parser'

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, eslint

I have sample installation of react-app and I got the following

> Error: Failed to load parser '@typescript-eslint/parser' declared in '.eslintrc » eslint-config-react-app#overrides[0]': Cannot find module 'typescript'

after running

```
 npm run lint -> eslint .
```

I don't use typescript in this project.
I tried to install it from scratch and got it again.
also tried to remove tslint from vscode plugin

Comment: npm install @typescript-eslint/parser  typescript

Comment: the GH issue is here: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8936

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can add this to your `.eslintignore` file in the root of your project.

```
node_modules
```

create-react-app team will release a new version with that fix also

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/8376

Comment: It does look to be the fact that `eslint .` with the current `overrides` that handle TypeScript mean that node_modules are also being linted for .ts/.tsx files. 

This PR was raised to work around it: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/9310

Using:
```
"lint": "eslint --ignore-path .gitignore .",
```

also works, as the default .gitignore ignores node_modules, and means a separate .eslintignore does not have to be maintained.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue when trying to create a new react app today.

You can try the following steps:

1. Make sure you **update your nodejs to the latest version**
2. Make sure your **folder path is short** and **does not contain spaces**
3. Run: `npm install -g create-react-app`
4. Run: `npm i --save-dev typescript @typescript-eslint/parser`
5. Run: `create-react-app my-app`

Comment: Had this issue in a craco-extended project. `npm i --save-dev typescript @typescript-eslint/parser` fixed it for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Create React App adds eslint config to `package.json`, so you just have to add `eslintIgnore` with `node_modules` in `package.json`. A cleaner alternative to creating a separate file `.eslintignore`

```
  // package.json
  // ...
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "eslintIgnore": [
    "node_modules",
    "build/*"
  ],
```

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, you have this in your `.eslintrc`:

```
extends: react-app
```

It means [the following rule is applied](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/f5c3bdb65480f93b2d4a4c2f3214fc50753de434/packages/eslint-config-react-app/index.js#L57-L69):

```
files: ['**/*.ts?(x)'], 
parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
```

Which probably means you have `*.ts`/`*.tsx` files in your root folder. But maybe it's the `vscode-eslint`. Did you try to run `yarn lint` from the terminal?

Answer (score 0):

Your error message says eslint is looking for typescript because of a setting in the file .eslintrc so try looking in that file for @typescript-eslint/parser and remove it.

Answer (score 0):

I was removing typescript from a project and I got the same error because I had forgotten a typescript definition somewhere under the src folder... deleting the file fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I wanted typescript, but didn't get it installed.
This question still helped me figure out my problem which is described below.

I was watching a [YouTube video, React Typescript Tutorial](https://youtu.be/Z5iWr6Srsj8?t=64) that explained how to get started with typescript and react, and the video said to run:

```
npx create-react-app cra-ts --typescript
```

This didn't work (but I didn't know it).  As soon as I created a hello.ts file, I got the error the OP describes.

> Error: Failed to load parser '@typescript-eslint/parser' declared in 'package.json » eslint-config-react-app#overrides[0]': Cannot find module 'typescript'

The fix was to use the command:

```
npx create-react-app myappts --template typescript
```

This used create-react-app@4.0.0 and react-scripts@4.0.0.

**ProTip: If your newly created React App doesn't have a file named App.tsx, then you haven't actually created it correctly.**

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I deleted the yarn lock as well as the yarn error log file that was created when I ran yarn.dev by mistake instead of npm start